# recover database data using GET variable

Tags: php, get

How do I recover a database row using a GET variable send from the previous page?

I have tried this:

```
        $username = $_GET["username"];

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users
        WHERE username=$username");
```

but it gives me the error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /homepages/12/d441172468/htdocs/cmd/play/index.php on line 33
```

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `$username` is a string, it must be quoted `WHERE username = '$username'`. But this is _highly_ vulnerable to SQL injection.  At a minimum, you must call `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get that error, you should immeditely add this debugging code:

```
var_dump(mysqli_error());
```

With that out of the way, here it's a fairly simple case of neglecting to put quotes around your variable. Also you fail to escape it so you're inviting Bobby Tables...

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='"
    .mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['username'])."'");
```